# How to prove that relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

On set ${\mathcal P(\{1, 2, 3, 4\})}$ given two relations R, S defined : for each ${A, B \in \mathcal P(\{1, 2, 3, 4\})}$ ${ARB}$ just if ${A \cap \{1, 2\} = B \cap \{1, 2\}}$ and ${ASB}$ just if ${A \cap \{1, 2\} \subset B \cap \{1, 2\}}$.

Task is prove that one of the relation is  equivalence relation and other partial order relation or full order relation?

As far as I see we can't prove any of them, because each of this kind of relation require to be reflexive, but it can't be reflexive because next doesn't satisfied

$${\forall a \in A * B \nrightarrow (a, b) \in R}$$

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: ${\forall a \in A * B \nrightarrow (a, b) \in R}$ is incoherent.  "As far as I see we can't prove any of them"  Leave me out of that surmise, speak for yourself only.

Comment: $ARA$ iff $A\cap\{1,2\}=A\cap\{1,2\}$, so $R$ is reflexive. Similarly $S$ is reflexive.

Comment: @almagest  but according to description we don't have relation ARA, not?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Explain further: why is ARA false?

Comment: If $f$ is some function with domain $X$ then the relation on $X$ prescribed by $xRy\iff f(x)=f(y)$ is an equivalence relation (try to prove this; not really difficult). Now apply this on $X:=\wp(\{1,2,3,4\})$ and the function $f$ prescribed by $A\mapsto A\cap\{1,2\}$.